# How to retain few changes and discard all other changes in git local branch?

Tags: git, github

I have locally committed few changes(wanted) on local branch. I want to rebase my local branch to remote master which has been updated with fixes. But there are other modifications/ untracked files (a lot many) which I don't want to retain. Now I can do 'git stash' then 'git stash drop' etc but that will discard all the changes including wanted. I am not sure how to go with this as I am new to git repository. Can anybody help with step by step process to accomplish this?

Comment: Pushing to a remote will only push what has been committed. Have you committed modifications you do not want to share, or are you only worried about the untracked files (and/or unstaged and uncommitted modifications) in your work folder? (In the second case, you may not need to "discard" anything.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `git add <filename>` to add files instead of adding all changes. Use [`git add -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add-patch) to add parts of files.

Verify staged code with `git diff --cached`. Verify with `git diff` that unstaged files don't contain anything you want to add.

Commit: `git commit`.

Discard unstaged changes: `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Now you're ready to rebase.

Comment: But when you run git reset --hard all those changes are lost? Perhaps he wants to keep them using stash?

Comment: *But there are other modifications … which I don't want to retain.* and *`git stash drop`* suggest that the OP really wants to discard them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw away all uncommitted changes in your working directory, you should use git-reset

`git reset --hard`

Merge remote master to your branch

`git rebase master <your_branch>`

In case you have any conflicts, correct them and continue rebase

`git rebase --continue`

Remove all untracked files and directories. (`-f` is `force`, `-d` is `remove directories`)
`git clean -fdx`